# Form Submit Confirmation in else statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good day. my problem is, the javascript alert doesn't work on else statement. In my else statement i want to show a javacript alert that the registration was succesful, but it doesn't appear.. here's my code

```
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['potpot'])){
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image'] ['name']);
$image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']);
if ($image_size==FALSE) { ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Oppss! Thats not an image!')</script>
 <?php
  }else{ ?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Wait for admin confirmation! Check your email     within 24 hours')</script>
   <?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"] ["tmp_name"], "images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$fullname= $_POST['name'];

$course=$_POST['course'];
$yeargrad=$_POST['year'];
$img=$_FILES['image']["name"];
$email=$_POST['email'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblreg(fullname,course,
        year_grad,img,email,username,password,status)



        VALUES('$fullname',
             '$course', '$yeargrad','$img', '$email', 'no', 'no', 'not')");

         header('location:reg.php');
         } 
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: add ; afte the alert like that alert('your message');

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which would have given you a warning message, stating that headers have already been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert does not appear because of redirect (`header('location:reg.php')`)

Comment: ohh thank you man, now i know that if we already used redirect we wont have to use alerts or vice versa.. ciao!